# Regex Solution Needed For Constraints

Tags: regex, aws-cloudformation

I'm sorry to be that guy, but I am really having issues setting up the regex for this and I have no clue what to do. I'm trying to setup my allowed patterns in a cloudformation template in aws but my pattern isn't necessary matching with what they actually allow. Here is a documentation of what they allow:

So basically abc-efg-hi is good.
abc-def- is bad
abc--def is bad
-abc-def is bag
abcefghi09 is good.

> DBClusterIdentifier
>   The DB cluster identifier. This parameter is stored as a lowercase string.
>
> Constraints:
>
> Must contain from 1 to 63 letters, numbers, or hyphens.
>
> First character must be a letter.
>
> Cannot end with a hyphen or contain two consecutive hyphens.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Regex: `^[a-z](?:(?![-]{2,})[a-z0-9-]){1,62}(?<!-)$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tHCmRI/2)

Comment: i've changed the regex to have `a-z0-9` in place of `\w` (to avoid upper case chars). Please see updated demo